# How to know if a client has closed their browser in socket.io

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I am using NODEJS+Socket.IO to control a raspberry pi pin. I have all the features working but I need to initiate a pin to be high if a client (user on the browser) closes the connection i.e closes their tab? 
Here is what I have tried

```
io.sockets.on('disconnect', function(){
  console.log("connection lost");
  });
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `socket.on("disconnect")`:

```
io.on("connection", socket => {
    socket.on("disconnect", () => console.log("Connection Lost"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I used the same thing except i placed it in the wrong scope!.

Comment: No worries @sakib11, always glad to help.

Comment: This will also prompt if the tab/browser is reloaded not just on closing a tab/browser.